# Explode nested JSON with Index using posexplode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Im using the below function to explode a deeply nested JSON (has nested struct and array).

```
# Flatten nested df  
def flatten_df(nested_df): 
        
    for col in nested_df.columns:
        array_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:5] == 'array']
    for col in array_cols:
        nested_df =nested_df.withColumn(col, F.explode_outer(nested_df[col]))

    nested_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct']
    
    if len(nested_cols) == 0:
        return nested_df

    flat_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct']

    flat_df = nested_df.select(flat_cols +
                            [F.col(nc+'.'+c).alias(nc+'_'+c)
                                for nc in nested_cols
                                for c in nested_df.select(nc+'.*').columns])

    return flatten_df(flat_df)
```

Im successfully able to explode. But I also want to add the order or the index of the elements in the exploded dataframe. So in the above code I replace the `explode_outer` function to `posexplode_outer`. But I get the below error

```
An error was encountered:
'The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF expected 2 aliases'
```

I tried changing the `nested_df.withColumn` to `nested_df.select` but I wasn't successful. Can anyone help me explode the nested json but same time maintain the order of array elements as a column in the exploded dataframe.

Comment: @please add a sample input data

Answer (score 0):

Read json data as dataframe and create view or table.In spark SQL you can use number of laterviewexplode method using alias reference. If json data structure  in struct type you can use dot to represent the structure. Level1.level2

Answer (score 0):

Replace `nested_df =nested_df.withColumn(col, F.explode_outer(nested_df[col]))` with   `nested_df = df.selectExpr("*", f"posexplode({col}) as (position,col)").drop(col)`

You might need to write some logic to replace the column names to original, but it should be simple

Answer (score 0):

The error is because posexplode_outer returns two columns pos and col, so you cannot use it along withColumn(). This can be used in select as shown in the code below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
tst= sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,7,80),(1,8,40),(1,5,100),(5,8,90),(7,6,50),(0,3,60)],schema=['col1','col2','col3'])
tst_new = tst.withColumn("arr",F.array(tst.columns))
expr = tst.columns
expr.append(F.posexplode_outer('arr'))
#%%
tst_explode = tst_new.select(*expr)
```

results:

```
tst_explode.show()
+----+----+----+---+---+
|col1|col2|col3|pos|col|
+----+----+----+---+---+
|   1|   7|  80|  0|  1|
|   1|   7|  80|  1|  7|
|   1|   7|  80|  2| 80|
|   1|   8|  40|  0|  1|
|   1|   8|  40|  1|  8|
|   1|   8|  40|  2| 40|
|   1|   5| 100|  0|  1|
|   1|   5| 100|  1|  5|
|   1|   5| 100|  2|100|
|   5|   8|  90|  0|  5|
|   5|   8|  90|  1|  8|
|   5|   8|  90|  2| 90|
|   7|   6|  50|  0|  7|
|   7|   6|  50|  1|  6|
|   7|   6|  50|  2| 50|
|   0|   3|  60|  0|  0|
|   0|   3|  60|  1|  3|
|   0|   3|  60|  2| 60|
+----+----+----+---+---+
```

If you need to rename the columns, you can use the .withColumnRenamed() function

```
df_final=(tst_explode.withColumnRenamed('pos','position')).withColumnRenamed('col','column')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try *select* with *list-comprehension* to posexplode the ArrayType columns in your existing code:

```
for col in array_cols:
  nested_df = nested_df.select([ F.posexplode_outer(col).alias(col+'_pos', col) if c == col else c for c in nested_df.columns ])
```

Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"n1", ["a", "b", "c"]),(2,"n2", ["foo", "bar"])],["id", "name", "vals"])
#+---+----+----------+
#| id|name|      vals|
#+---+----+----------+
#|  1|  n1| [a, b, c]|
#|  2|  n2|[foo, bar]|
#+---+----+----------+
      
col = "vals" 
    
df.select([F.posexplode_outer(col).alias(col+'_pos', col) if c == col else c for c in df.columns]).show()
#+---+----+--------+----+
#| id|name|vals_pos|vals|
#+---+----+--------+----+ 
#|  1|  n1|       0|   a|
#|  1|  n1|       1|   b| 
#|  1|  n1|       2|   c| 
#|  2|  n2|       0| foo|
#|  2|  n2|       1| bar| 
#+---+----+--------+----+
```